# Auto open search results

Tags: list, search

The scenario we have is a large list containing several 1000 items with at least two unique indexed columns.

What we'd like is for a user to search for one of these unique fields and resulting item to be displayed instantly on the search page, by this I mean the actual display form, not a list of search results. Each search query should only come up with a single result.

I've played around a bit with search query/results webparts but am still not achieving what I'm after.

It seems like something so basic, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could configure a Query Rule to do this. Set the number of results to 1 and render the item in your Display Template.